# Original version of a quotation attributed to Eugene Sue

Tags: traduction

Consider this [quotation](https://www.google.com.au/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&biw=1386&bih=640&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks&ei=PzPPW8rVEZrk-Abez7y4CA&q=%22Virtue%20often%20trips%20and%20falls%20on%20the%22%20%22sharp-%20edged%20rock%20of%20poverty%22&oq=%22Virtue%20often%20trips%20and%20falls%20on%20the%22%20%22sharp-%20edged%20rock%20of%20poverty%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21829.36899.0.37378.12.12.0.0.0.0.299.1743.2-7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.1.264...33i10k1.0.7ZYFBfVmMYs) attributed to Eugene Sue:

> Virtue, alas! not infrequently trips and falls on the sharp-edged rock of poverty.

It has been attributed in the work "The Mysteries of Paris" but a search of the [four English tr. volumes](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%28Eugene%20Sue%29%20AND%20mediatype%3A%28texts%29) has not borne fruit. Neither any luck at sites like [babelio](https://www.babelio.com/auteur/Eugene-Sue/6810/citations?a=a&pageN=1), so perhaps the default Google translation is missing something.

> La vertu, hélas! fréquents voyages et tombe sur le rocher acéré de la pauvreté

Any alternatives to help locate a source?
Thanks.

Comment: Il y a tout d'abord une flagrante imprécision à éliminer dans la traduction Google, il faut absolument que « to trip » signifie « trébucher » dans ce contexte-ci! (pas «voyager»); ensuite il est préférable de rester près de l'original et de préserver « edge »; cela mis à part cette traduction littérale se prête apparemment très bien à l'original anglais: « La vertu, hélas… doit fréquemment trébucher et tomber sur le rocher aux arêtes acérées de la pauvreté ».

Answer (score 3):

Mon opinion est qu'il ne faut pas chercher sur google la traduction d'une traduction.

Je ne sais dire de quelle traduction anglaise cette citation est reprise, mais je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'une traduction mot à mot.

Dans le volume 4 des *Mystères de Paris*, Eugène Sue évoque effectivement cette idée de danger que la pauvreté représente pour la vertu mais, sous cette forme :

"*N'est-il pas évident que ces instincts salutaires pourraient devenir des principes arrêtés chez **les infortunés que l'ignorance et la pauvreté exposent incessamment à la subversive obsession du mal**.*"

Comment: I assumed originally that Eugene Sue was citing an old proverbe. Interesting that a translator would make such an interpretation on that piece. Also note the key words of the translated quote are virtue and poverty. Do you think vertu is implied in your extract?

Comment: @LaurieStearn : Il est beaucoup question de *vertu* (républicaine) chez Sue. Or, à ma compréhension, les *instincts salutaires devenant des principes arrếtés*, c'est très précisément cela qu'est la *vertu*.

Comment: @Laurie It 's  conceivable that "instincts salutaires" although in conception not a basis  for action justified on the tenets of religion be assimilable to vertue, although that appears somewhat far-fetched; the particular instincts referred to should be made clear first, so as to see if they can identify closely enough with virtue, be it religious or civil vertue.